# Allowing any MAC admin user to run MySQL server on startup

Tags: mysql, wordpress, macos, mamp

I recently installed MAMP on our server in order to launch a Wordpress site. Though everything is working fine I am not the computer's main user, something which results in long downtime when it has to be rebooted for maintenance.

I was looking for a way to automatically load MAMP on start-up, regardless of who logs in. This lead me to run a script for loading the Apache and MySQL servers on start-up, using the files *startApache.sh* and *startMysql.sh* located in *Applications/MAMP/bin*. I found that the Apache server could be loaded from any admin user with no problem. The MySQL server however will only start when I log-in with my own account (which is the one under which the installation took place).

Being able to run these scripts without being prompted for a password would be a plus, but it is more important that any admin can start the MySQL server.

I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want to do is [Install mysql as a service so it starts on mac startup.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/automatic-start.html)

This info should help you do that:
[Installing the MySQL Startup Item](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/macosx-installation-startupitem.html)

Also, [this is a good tutorial on setting up MAMP to start up silently](http://stringfoo.com/2008/08/25/tutorial-launching-mamp-silently-on-startup/).